# Fail on second call

Tags: python, asynchronous, call

I need your help please.

This code only works once, a second wget gives timeout (attached file).

> wget http://localhost:9090

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import trollius as asyncio
from trollius import From
import os

class Client(asyncio.Protocol):

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.connected = True
        # save the transport
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        # forward data to the server
        self.server_transport.write(data)

    def connection_lost(self, *args):
        self.connected = False

class Server(asyncio.Protocol):
    clients = {}

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        # save the transport
        self.transport = transport

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def send_data(self, data):
        # get a client by its peername
        peername, port = self.transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        client = self.clients.get(peername)
        # create a client if peername is not known or the client disconnect
        if client is None or not client.connected:
            protocol, client = yield From(loop.create_connection(Client, 'google.com', 80))
            client.server_transport = self.transport
            self.clients[peername] = client
        # forward data to the client
        client.transport.write(data)

    def data_received(self, data):
        # use a task so this is executed async
        asyncio.Task(self.send_data(data))

@asyncio.coroutine
def initialize(loop):
    # use a coroutine to use yield from and get the async result of
    # create_server
    server = yield From(loop.create_server(Server, '127.0.0.1', 9090))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# main task to initialize everything
asyncio.Task(initialize(loop))

# run
loop.run_forever()
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the error log if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need a real 'loop' in servers when you are writing socket servers in asyncio. Note that despite 'sync' coding, infinite loops do not block execution here. You need an infinite while loop within your server. There are many samples,I recommend [websockets](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets) library samples!